# Explain GAM model output plot in r

Tags: r, plot, gam, mgcv

I used gam model to explain fish catch (cpue) variation with enviromnetal parameters (sst, chl) in the ocean.

```
model9<-gam(log(cpue)~s(lon,lat), data=c1)
summary(model9)  
plot(model9)
plot(model9, scheme = 2)
```

Result as follows

```
Family: gaussian 
Link function: identity 

Formula:
log(cpue) ~ s(lon, lat)

Parametric coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) -1.13478    0.03218  -35.27   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Approximate significance of smooth terms:
             edf Ref.df     F p-value   
s(lon,lat) 15.92  20.69 2.242 0.00151 **
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

R-sq.(adj) =  0.0771   Deviance explained = 10.6%
GCV = 0.5514  Scale est. = 0.53328   n = 515
```

[image]

[image]

I want to know, how to explain the plot. what are the meaning of these lines and values?

Comment: black solid line is the smoother, i.e. the modeled mean fish catch base don the lat-lon. the red and green dash lines are the different std error from the smoother.

Comment: For a 2D smoother I find the output of `plot(model, scheme = 2)` usually easier to interpret.

Comment: The black lines are isolines. Green and red lines show the uncertainty of these isolines.

Comment: @Roland I added result of plot(model9, scheme = 2). Then what would be the interpretation? I would like to know which areas have a high association and which are not.

Comment: What exactly does " high association" mean?

Comment: @Roland, I mean high association the value of contour or its location may give a  high fish catch. example 0.3 contour located in (80,7)

Comment: " its location may give a high fish catch. example 0.3 contour located in (80,7)" If your dependent variable is fish catch, you have correctly identified such an area in the plot. However, take into account if any/how many data points are in this area.